# How to control plot type for each of multiple dependent variables in lattice xyplot?

Tags: r, lattice

Suppose you have a dataset with multiple dependent variables for one dependent variable. With `xyplot` you can plot them simply as `xyplot(y1+y2~x, data=d)`. How would you plot `y1` with one plot type (e.g. points), and `y2` with a different plot type (e.g. lines)?

A reproducible example:

```
my.df <- data.frame(time=c(1:20), lower.lim=runif(n=20, min=1,max=4),
                    upper.lim=runif(n=20, min=6,max=9),
                    observed=runif(n=20,min=0,max=10))

xyplot(lower.lim + upper.lim + observed ~ time, data=my.df, type=c("p","l"))
```

Plot `lower.lim` and `upper.lim` as `type="s"`, and `observed` as `type=c("p","l")`

I'm thinking this should be doable with custom `panel` functions, but I can't figure out how to operate on each dependent variable separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `panel.groups` within `panel.superpose`, along with the `group.number` argument, to detect which variable is currently being drawn.

```
panelfun <- function(...,type,group.number) {
    if (group.number==3) {
        panel.points(...)
        panel.lines(...)
    } else {
        panel.points(...,type="s")
    }
}

xyplot(lower.lim+upper.lim+observed ~ time, data=my.df,
    panel=function(...) panel.superpose(...,panel.groups=panelfun),
       col=c(1,1,2))
```